# How to fetch email headers properly

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm using `imap_fetchheader()` to retrieve header info of an email message. For some emails   this message id is empty. But when i check the same email through webmail message id is present.

Is there anyway to fetch all header info without any issues?

Comment: Try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php

Comment: i tried it without success.. not all messages shows empty message id, only some of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not with the `imap_fetchheader()` . Message in email header will be like this:

```
<e5d22200ed6ca211cbc1d12de63f1383@192.168.0.25>
```

I think, for some message ids, browser thinks it as html tag and prints. Issue resolved when i convert it using htmlentities() ex:

```
htmlentities( imap_fetchheader($conn, "1"))
```

how silly the answer is...!